# Hiding processes on Unix/Linux

Tags: process, freebsd, proc, shared-library

I found an [interesting article](https://sysdig.com/blog/hiding-linux-processes-for-fun-and-profit/) about how to hide specific processes on linux from process monitoring tools like `ps`, `top`, `lsof`, ...

Person states that there are several possible ways to hide processes:

> 1. **Using a proper framework**: there are a bunch of very good frameworks, like `SELinux` and `Grsecurity` that do, among other
>      things, exactly this. In a production system, I would absolutely
>      consider these, although today I want to  get my hands dirty and have
>      fun creating something from scratch.
> 2. **Modify `top/ps/...` binaries**: I could grab the source code of each of these tools, implement my own *"hiding linux processes"*
>      logic, recompile, and replace the binaries. Very inefficient and time
>      consuming.
> 3. **Modify `libc`**: I could modify the `readdir()` function inside `libc` and input the code to exclude the access to some `/proc` files.
>      But recompiling `libc` is a burden, not to mention the `libc` code
>      tends to be very hard to understand.
> 4. **Modify the system calls in the kernel**: This is the most advanced, and it would work by intercepting and modifying the `getdents()`
>      system call directly in the kernel with a custom module. It’s
>      definitely tempting, but I won’t follow this route today because I’m
>      already very familiar with how the system call interception works in
>      `sysdig`, so I want to do something new.
>
> I decided to go for an intermediate solution, one that is interesting
>   and simple enough to implement in an hour or so: it’s a variant of
>   **"modifying libc"** based on a tricky feature offered by the *Linux dynamic linker* (the component that takes care of loading the various
>   libraries needed by a program at runtime), called *preloading*.
>
> With *preloading*, Linux is kind enough to give us the option to load a
>   custom shared library before the other normal system libraries are
>   loaded. This means that, if the custom library exports a function with
>   the same signature of one found in a system library, we are literally
>   able to override it with the custom code in our library, and all the
>   processes will automatically pick our custom one!
>
> This sounds like a solution to my problem, because I could write a
>   very simple custom library that overrides libc's `readdir()`, and write
>   the logic to hide the process! The logic would be fairly
>   straightforward too: every time I see that the `/proc/PID` directory
>   (where *PID* is the *PID of the process* having the name `"evil_script"`) is
>   being read, I just block that access in a clean way, thus hiding the
>   entire directory! I went ahead and implemented these thoughts in code.
>   You can get the sources at
>   https://github.com/gianlucaborello/libprocesshider/blob/master/processhider.c
>   (it’s actually less than 100 lines of code including comments, so go
>   read it!). Once the code is written, let’s compile it as a shared
>   library, and install it in the system path.

**Source code**: [processhider.c](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/libprocesshider/blob/master/processhider.c)

So the steps are:

1. `make` => `gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o libprocesshider.so processhider.c -ldl`
2. `mv libprocesshider.so /usr/local/lib/` (as *root*)
3. `echo /usr/local/lib/libprocesshider.so >> /etc/ld.so.preload`

---

**Now back to my question/problem**: Here it is described for *Linux systems*. I tested it on my Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit) machine and everything worked fine - process was now hidden from `ps`. Additionally I tested it on my another machine where FreeBSD 11.0 (64 bit) is installed.

First I had to remove following part of the code:

```
DECLARE_READDIR(dirent64, readdir64);
```

because I got an error (`dirent64` wasn't defined in *dirent.h* - I just used `locate dirent.h` and compared the code to some internet sources):

```
processhider.c: In function 'readdir64':
processhider.c:87:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct dirent64'
                 get_process_name(dir->d_name, process_name) &&          \
                                     ^
processhider.c:97:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DECLARE_READDIR'
 DECLARE_READDIR(dirent64, readdir64);
 ^
*** Error code 1
```

After removing `DECLARE_READDIR(dirent64, readdir64);` I got another error complaining about `-ldl` flag:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc5 -Wall -fPIC -shared -o libprocesshider.so processhider.c -ldl
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1

Stop.
```

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary) where one could replace `-ldl` with `-L/usr/local/lib` where my `libdl.so` file is located (meaning of "[collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272525/what-does-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-mean/32711542)" error).

Then I was able to compile the code. I placed the library into `/usr/local/lib/` and added it to `/etc/ld.so.preload`.

However when I called my script `evil_script.py` (Code was different (no more UDP packets spam), but I still have `while true` loop and `time.sleep(60)` so the process should be there) it still appeared in the process list (`ps auxww`). Maybe `/etc/ld.so.preload` is not working? Can be there some problem with `ld.so` shared library? Is there any way how I can test what goes wrong at which point?

Comment: The `ps` and `top` on *BSD don't work by reading files and dirs off `/proc`, but by using the `sysctl` system call and by directly reading the kernel memory via `/dev/mem`. So overriding the `readdir`, etc cannot have any effect on them. In general, this whole endeavor is kind of pointless -- there are so many ways to bypass it, it isn't even funny.

Comment: You can't, unless you hack into kernel(sysdig needs a non-upstream kernel module to work). But obviously you can fake the process list when using a userspace tool by simply replace the binary with a custom version, or replace the library with customized function. Notice the actual path to achive this might be seccomp, ptrace.

Comment: that was my idea too -  just to replace the binary with my own one. seems to be way simpler.

Comment: @mosvy, do you know any other ways to bypass it? Are those ways different as described in my question? If yes, then it would be probably way better if I would ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 and 3 (modifying ps, top, libraries), is prone to walk around breach. E.g. an attacker can just use there own `ps`.

A better way would be to block these tools from accessing info on processes of other users. Then running the processes to be hidden as a different user.

For the 1st part, edit `/etc/fstab`, to include

```
#protect /proc
proc /proc proc defaults,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=2,gid=admin 0 0
```